# Logstash Elasticsearch Output with specific fields to index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is there possibility for logstash to ingest whole document to one index and specific fields to other index in the elastic search output.

Example: If i have 10 fields coming in from input , can i write all the fields to one index and some specific fields to other index.

my current logstash is like

```
input{
kafka input
}
filter{
fingerprint id will be generated using some fields
}
output{
elastic{
whole document should go into this index
}
elastic{
Only the fingerprint field should go into this index
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, please show your current Logstash config.

Comment: You can make use of pipelines feature of logstash to do that. You have to specify multiple logstash configuration files in the pipelines.yml and run logstash without any command line parameters.

Comment: i added the logstash config to question

Comment: In the filter block, you can drop fields